# Как тут после сообщения отправить переменную Telebot

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

'''
bot.send_photo(file, "cool")
Как после слова cool отправить переменную
Ss = yes

Я сделал вотак не сработало "cool", ss)
'''

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, изучите документацию перед тем, как задавать такие вопросы.
https://pytba.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/sync_version/index.html?highlight=send_photo#telebot.TeleBot.send_photo

Чтобы отправить фото с подписью, в которой будет переменная, вам нужно использовать f-строки. f-строки позволяют добавлять значения переменных в текст.
Например,

```
i = 1
print(f"Число: {i}")
```

В консоль этот код выведет

Число: 1

Аналогичным способом вы записываете f"cool {ss}".
В следующий раз, будьте добры, почитайте документацию. В ней даже есть поиск.